# MS Access VBA - Filter form using Date

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am wrestling with a task to filter a form based on a date criteria.  I think I am munging the date format somehow and cannot find a combination that will return a result.  There are valid dates on the subform; criteria should return a result - but returns ZERO records.  I tried the DATE function as well as explicit #10/17/2017# type values.

```
Dim strFilter As String

Select Case Me!frmFilter.Value

    Case 1  'All
        Forms![InventoryList].[InventoryList subform].Form.FilterOn = False
    Case 2  'Active
        strFilter = "Forms![InventoryList].[InventoryList subform].Form.[StartDate] > #" & Date & "#"
        Forms![InventoryList].[InventoryList subform].Form.Filter = strFilter
        Forms![InventoryList].[InventoryList subform].Form.FilterOn = True
    Case 3  'Pending
        'do something else

End Select

End Sub
```

Any suggestions to help me move this task forward a little bit?

Thanks!

Comment: What data type is the `StartDate` in Access?

Comment: "StartDate" is coming from a Query, formatted as "General Date"..  The source table for the query is defined as "Date/Time".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to work if `StartDate` is a *date* and `[InventoryList subform]` is the name of the subform *control*:

```
Select Case Me!frmFilter.Value
    Case 1  'All
        Forms![InventoryList]![InventoryList subform].Form.FilterOn = False
    Case 2  'Active
        strFilter = "[StartDate] > Date()"
        Forms![InventoryList]![InventoryList subform].Form.Filter = strFilter
        Forms![InventoryList]![InventoryList subform].Form.FilterOn = True
    Case 3  'Pending
        'do something else
End Select
```

Comment: Thank you.  Works just as expected. Eric was also on the right track, but still I missed the bus and over-complicated the filter.